# AngularJS UI Grid: How do I make a cell with multiple lines?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, user-interface, cell

I am trying to make a angular ui gird and if I have a lot of data going into a cell, it doesn't display all of it because the cell isn't big enough.

In this [Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/KMlxQewFT5K3zNB7RA8n?p=preview/), it says:

```
I want this sen...
```

rather than

```
I want this sentence to continue onto the next line rather then the '...'. Can you help?
```

I want this sentence to be on multiple lines rather than one long line.

Comment: Can you please post a plnkr or something? Anyway, I believe the solution is css based.  You can try playing with text-overflow of the cells.

Comment: @yccteam Here you go http://plnkr.co/edit/KMlxQewFT5K3zNB7RA8n

Comment: Is this the desired effect?
http://plnkr.co/edit/vKrL6OVMWiPhyUCWdYlp?p=preview

Comment: I dont see anything working. All I see is the "cell template: ". Can you send it again with a new link? Thanks

Comment: Look at the "First Name" column. See that the 3 dots are missing, and the rest of the text is wrapped (but hidden under the cells below).

Comment: The dots are missing and I can see it hidden. Just got to make the cell expand, so it shows the whole sentence.

Comment: Ok - so what you want is to set the row's height according to its content? This is more tricky than it sounds, since it conflicts with the virtual scroll.  My suggestion is to keep the `...` and set the tooltip feature to true, so it would show the full contents on hover.